# How to add comma inside parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Peace be upon you.
I have these arguments:

```
clickFun('fas', 'fa-check-circle');
```

and this function:

```
function clickFun(addCls) {
        Target.classList.add(addCls);
```

how I can let the browser consider `'fas', 'fa-check-circle` as one argument?

Comment: Remove the quotes. But this will just cause `.add` to throw a `InvalidCharacterError`. If you want both classes to be added you have to either add them by hand one at a time or you have to find a way how `clickFun` can handle multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arguments object with spread operator**

You can use the array-like [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to access an indefinite number of arguments passed to the function. Combined with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a solution would look like the following.

```js
const Target = document.querySelector('.target');

function clickFun() {
  Target.classList.add(...arguments);
}

clickFun('fas', 'fa-check-circle');
```

```css
.target {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fas {
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class='target'></div>
```

**Array with spread operator**

But a more practical solution would be to change `clickFun()` to accept an array, and still use the spread operator to spread the passed array to a list of strings.

```js
const Target = document.querySelector('.target');

function clickFun(addCls) {
  Target.classList.add(...addCls);
}

const classesToAdd = ['fas', 'fa-check-circle'];
clickFun(classesToAdd);
```

```css
.target {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fas {
  background-color: pink;
}

.fa-check-circle {
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class='target'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach

```
clickFun(['fas', 'fa-check-circle']);

function clickFun(classesArray) {
    classesArray.forEach(el => {
        Target.classList.add(el);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array and then for loop to add classes inside array
this is also fastest way to add classes to elements

```
let classes = ["fas","fas-check-circle"];
function clickFun(classes) {
    for(let i in classes){
        Target.classList.add(classes[i]);
    } 
}
clickFun(classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two arguments, just one. The selectors are separated by blank spaces ( ), so if you pass "fas fa-check-circle" together, the classList.add method will understand like two different classes.

```
clickFun('fas fa-check-circle');

...

function clickFun(addCls) {
    Target.classList.add(addCls);
}
```